# Convert a part of a string into upper case

Tags: powershell

I am automatically obtaining directories from an application but I can't seem to get the actual directories with the correct case of letters.

For example I get `$a='C:\test\dir\log\wqerst'` but the actual directory is `C:\test\dir\log\WQERST`.

What I want is to uppercase only `wqerst` so it would show `C:\test\dir\log\WQERST`

I've already tried using `substring` but I don't know how I would be able to connect it to the whole directory once it is uppercase.

Comment: Windows is case insensitive so it shouldn't matter about capitals in a path, if you're connecting to a unix-based OS it would be different.

Comment: NTFS itself [is case sensitive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/100625/filenames-are-case-sensitive-on-ntfs-volumes), but Win32 API doesn't care.

Comment: I dont know but I tried an i am unable to go to the directory if its not in the right case

Comment: Just an update, yes they are correct, i just had a mistake on another part of my code which is changing the leaf path of the script into a non existent one, mistyped 2 characters, which is hard to notice cause i just glanced at it, but yeah i traced it and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Windows system is not case sensitive, but if you want really this result, you can do it :

```
$a='C:\test\dir\log\wqerst' 
$parentpath=Split-Path -Path $a
$file=(Split-Path -Path $a -Leaf).ToUpper()
$result=Join-Path $parentpath $file

$result
```

Answer (score 1):

As [James C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2208505/james-c) and [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) already wrote, there is not much point to get the case sensitive folder path. However you can use this helper method:

```
function Get-CaseSensitiveFilePath
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$FilePath
    )
    $parent = Split-Path $FilePath
    $leaf = Split-Path -Leaf $FilePath

    $result = Get-ChildItem $parent | where { $_ -like $leaf }
    $result.FullName
}
```

**usage:**

```
Get-CaseSensitiveFilePath -FilePath 'C:\test\dir\log\WQERST'
```

This will give you the case sensitive folder name but the directory must exist on the computer you execute the script...

Comment: Hi thanks you very much for this, this actually works, but I'd like to understand this further, cause im quite very noob with powershell

Comment: I would recommend you to debug the script with the PowerShell ISE so you can see what the lines return. Basically the first line gets the parent path of filepath you passed to the function. The second line retrieve the last directory (in your case WQERST). Then I use the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to retrieve all directories and select the leaf directory using the Where-Object cmdlet. Finally I return the full directory path.